# serializar item da classes em documentos textuais

Tags: c#

Gostaria de pegar os elementos da minha classe products e gravar um arquivo txt como ficaria meu método de Serialização.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var products = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product(1, "KEYLG1", "Keyboard Logitech", 78.9),
            new Product(2, "MOULG1", "Mouse M280 Logitech", 55.5),
            new Product(3, "SMGM01", "Samgsung DUOS", 234.9),
            new Product(4, "NTASUS", "Notebooke Asus", 3500.99)
        };

        var fileName = @"c:\temp\Products.txt";    
        Serialize(fileName, products);      

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializa os dados aqui.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <param name="products"></param>
    private static void Serialize(string fileName, List<Product> products)
    {


        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: você quer gravar cada informação separada por `;` exemplo `1;KEYLG1;Keyboard Logitech; 78.9` ou algum outro formato? fiquei na duvida sobre isso.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode gerar um xml, arquivo binário ou em json..

Para fazer salvar em texto, modo xml..

Marque a classe `Product` com o atributo `Serializable`

```
[Serializable]
public class Product
{
  //propriedades..
  //métodos...
  //..
}
```

Para Gravar:

```
private static void Serialize(string fileName, List<Product> products){
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(products.GetType());
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, products);
    }
}
```

Para ler do arquivo:

```
public static List<Product> LerExemplo(String pathArquivo){
    if (!File.Exists(pathArquivo))
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Arquivo não encontrado " + pathArquivo);

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Product>));
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(pathArquivo))
    {
        var produtos = (List<Product>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        return produtos;
    }
}
```

Veja o arquivo gerado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Opa marcos muito obrigado, mas desta forma eu gravo meu arquivo binário não seria? preciso gravar texto

Comment: Não desta forma você grava em modo XML, se abrir com bloco de notas, notepad++.. vai poder editar o conteúdo.

Comment: Editei a resposta adicionando uma imagem do arquivo gerado.

Comment: Valeu de mais meu caro, resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Em json, usando Newtonsoft.Json:
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm

```
Product product = new Product();
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);

JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\json.txt"))
using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, product);
    // {"ExpiryDate":new Date(1230375600000),"Price":0}
}
```